# $C$-conjugation of a gluon

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons, charge-conjugation

In some explanations about the OZI rule ( for example at page 38 [here](http://www.roma1.infn.it/%7Eluci/fns/2017/Colour_QCD.pdf)), I found that gluons have definite eigenvalue of the charge conjugation operator $C$. The eigenvalue is $-1$. How can this result be demonstrated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you "found" it. The off-diagonal gluons, like $\bar R G$, are not eigenstates, since they transform to their antigluon, here $\bar G R$.

The color-diagonal ones, like $\bar R R - \bar G G$, would naturally associate with the vector mesons with an analogous flavor structure to this color structure. I assume you have worked out the charge conjugation of the $\rho^0$, or the $^3S_1$ orthopositronium, namely  −.  That is, unphysical, strictly combinatorially, if your diagonal gluon "decayed" to a notional fermion-antifermion pair with these colors, its *C* would be −.

---

*Note in response to comment and ref*

You don’t understand  your ref's statement because it is wrong, or, at best, sloppy (and, in any case, subpar); only three gluons in a colorless state have negative C. The point is the color coupling $ig_s G^\mu_{\bar RG}\overline{\psi_G}\gamma_\mu \psi_R + h.c.$ (representing $\lambda_+$ in your p.5 conventions, unlike the diagonal $\lambda_3$ I used above!) should remind you of the EM coupling   $ie A^\mu\bar\psi\gamma_\mu \psi + h.c.$ which goes to itself under C, so the photon is odd, since the current is odd; except the color coupling goes to $\lambda_-$,  hence cannot be an eigenstate! So, the only gluons that *are* eigenstates of *C* are $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_8$. Still, by taking the trace of three such color matrices, however, you may find a *C*-invariant combination of the fermion sextilinear, and so "pretend" each gluon *G* comes with an odd *C* eigenvalue, just like the photon. Your reference is "summarizing" all this in code, with a wink and a "you know", and you are within your rights to not be fully satisfied. There is no substitute to going back to your QFT text and checking the Dirac couplings defining *C* the normal way.

Comment: Unfortunately the language you used appears too complicated for my level. Maybe the link that I added to the question could help you to focus my problem better. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The EM coupling term should be Hermitian. It is actually $\mathcal{H} = e j_\mu A^\mu = e A^\mu \bar \psi  \gamma_\mu \psi$. No i in the interaction term